# Как собрать и запустить веб-приложение (java ee(ejb)+react) на glassfish

Tags: reactjs, java-ee, maven, glassfish, web-apps

У меня есть приложение, которое использует java ee(ejb) для бэка и реакт для  фронта. Бэк я могу легко собрать мавеном в варник и задеплоить на glassfish. Но мне совсем непонятно как запустить там свой фронт и заставить его работать вместе с бэком.

Comment: Спасибо, исправил

Comment: это другое дело ..

Comment: Бэк отдельно, фронт отдельно.
Запускаете бэк. А фронт у вас использует точки входа бэкэнда.

Comment: спасибо, в принципе я почитал про вебпак и вроде все работает